# Memcached for BI Reporting

Tags: architecture, memcached, amazon-rds, business-intelligence

I tried to get the answer from AWS blogs and other question and answer forum but couldn't get.

Can we use a caching service like Memcached or Redis in front of a DB (Any relational DB) which are used for BI reporting to increase the cache hit and make the queries faster.

user-->query-->memcache/redis-->DB

I am yet to see any architecture similar to this. Please let me know if anyone has implemented this architecture.

Comment: I've seen elasticsearch be used to power reports to speed up load times. I'm also curious of other technologies or use cases that have been used for this use case.